# Create string from a number range

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq

Is there a way to make this a one liner?

```
List<string> ids = new List<string>(result.Count);
for(int i = 0; i < result.Count; i++)
    ids.Add(i.ToString());
string reportIds = String.Join(",", ids);
```

I'm pretty sure there's a way with linq, but I can't figure out

Comment: Why not `string reportIds = String.Join(",", result);`?

Comment: install resharper, it always finds a way to make things 1 line :D

Comment: just make sure if you didnt mean to ask about  ids.Add(result[i].ToString()); Then all the answers are wrong, as was your questions :P

Comment: @mikus I know, I do use resharper on my personal development enviroment, but I'm working on a company laptop i was assigned, so the software I can install first must go through a approval by IT and if the project budget allows it I can have resharper installed. Sadly, it was turn down

Comment: @haim770 Results is a list of objects, there's no property that gives the object index on the list, and I needed a list of the indexes joined in a string by a comma, that's the way the webservice I'm using this on received the indexes

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`string.Join()` actually takes `IEnumerable<object>` in one of its overloads so there is no need to call `ToString()` yourself. Here is the complete one-liner using `Enumerable.Range()`:

```
var reportIds = string.Join(",", Enumerable.Range(0, result.Count));
```

Comment: Love your answer more. I'm a sucker for 1 liners, >D

Answer (score 4):

```
string reportIds = String.Join(",",Enumerable.Range(0, result.Count));
```

Answer (score 2):

```
string str = String.Join(",", Enumerable.Range(0, count).Select(n => n.ToString()));
```

Comment: Forgot about `Enumerable.Range`, thanks, used ReSharper for this kind of tips, but I'm not allowed to install it